How to deserialize Java object when private field type has changed?
I have a Java class with fields of different types (serialVersionUID is present among them). One of the fields is of type Integer and it always holds value 0 or 1. When previous version of my app was launched, object of this class was serialized and is stored in DB as text.
Now I have changed my code and this Integer field is of type Boolean. I would like to deserialize "old" object from DB and map 0/1 values to false/true accordingly.
How to achieve that?
I tried to create custom implementation of readObject() method in my class but without success.
What is important is that I need to have the possibility to deserialize both versions of my object - the old one with Integer field and the new one with Boolean field because I do not know which version I would need to restore from DB and deserialize.

This part: object of this class was serialized and is stored in DB as text. makes no sense when you combine it with serialVersionUID is present among them. What is the process by which you serialize? If it's java's serialization mechanism, which uses serialVersionUID and involves readObject(), then it is not possible to store the result as text because its bytes, not text. Possibly you think you can do that and you are going to run into charset issues. Given that this is now unclear, this question should be updated with the code you use to write, and read, your objects as it is now.

In this case, perhaps the easiest solution is to remove the old access if any, i.e. int getXyz() and void setXyz(int v), and replace them with a synthetic property of type boolean:
public void setNewProperty(boolean value) {
    this.old = value ? 1:0;
}

public boolean isNewProperty() {
    return old == 1;
}

